# The word "array" prints instead of databse information

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, printing

My code keeps on print the word "array" instead of the database information. When i try to use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` it echos all the information about the array

this is with `var_dump`

array(1) { ["Team"]=> string(8) "Oakville" } array(1) { ["Team"]=> string(8) "Brampton" } array(1) { ["Team"]=> string(7) "Toronto" } array(1) { ["Team"]=> string(11) "Mississauga" }

Here's my code

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit2'])){
$leaguename = $_POST['league'];
$db_host = '**';
$db_user = '**';
$db_pwd = '**';
$database = '**';
$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd, $database);


$sql = "SELECT Team FROM Games WHERE League = '$leaguename' AND Team <> ''";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die ("no query");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $array[] = $row;
}

$teamnumber=count($array);
echo $teamnumber . "<br>";

foreach($array as $teams=>$team){
    var_dump($team);
}
```

I'm trying to print the names of sports teams that are being fetched from a database and put into an array.

Comment: I cannot spot any printing command in there...

Comment: You don't echo the array, you echo individual elements from the array; `foreach($array as $teams=>$team){
    echo $team['Team'];
}`

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. You are using mysqli so use the prepared functionality of it. 1. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @MarkBaker OMG BLESS UR SOUL IT WORKED BLESS

Answer (score 0):

Your array is a Multidimensional Arrays, an array containing one or more arrays.

Because of that you are printing the outer array `var_dump()`. You should use a double loop:

```
foreach($array as $teams){
    foreach($teams as $team){
        echo $team . "<br>";
    }
}
```